# connecting application with device driver

Tags: c, device-driver

This is an interview question.

I had written device driver for a char device so I know that code structure looks like this

```
struct file_operations something {
 .owner=my_device_open;
 .read=my_device_read;
 .close=my_device_close;
 .write=my_device_write;

 }
```

When the device driver is active then in

```
/dev/mydevice
```

you can actually read and write into it.
But what I was not clear is how an application will read or write to this device.
I know `insmod` will insert the module to kernel,and `register_chrdev();` will register the driver in kernel but how will application program communicate with this driver.
Let me know what will be correct answer for it.

Answer (score 2):

Well Martin Beckett summed it up. It is not really more complex,
although you could say the same with slightly more detail. Here is my
try at it:

The program performs an `open("/dev/mydevice", flags)` syscall, then the
kernel reads `/dev/mydevice` from disk. It is just an inode, with no
associated data blocks, but it holds two important pieces of
information: the major number and the minor number. From these numbers,
the kernel finds the `struct file_operations` that you provided through
`register_chrdev()`, and it calls it's `.open` field. It returns to the
program a file descriptor that it associated with this particular
`struct file_operations`. Next, when the kernel receives a syscall like
`write(fd, buf, count)`, it will call the `.write` field and so on.

Comment: hmmm well I had exactly told the same thing which you mentioned but seemed that my interviewer was not convinced with what I told.

Comment: So you did mention the major and minor numbers in the inode? Well, your interviewer in kind of weird. Maybe he expected a very specific piece of information, like the exact kernel in-memory structure for an open file, or how is is linked from the task structure, or whatever... and he did not want to tell you what he was actually expecting.

Comment: I have no idea I was asked this same question in 2 different interviews whose result they did not revealed.

Answer (score 1):

In unix it simply opens the device node as a file and sends/receives data and commands from it.
The beauty of Unix is that from an app's point of view there is nothing special about devices - they are just files (except for ioctls to set some modes). There is work to do in the kernel to accomodate this but that's the kernel modules problem.

Or were you asking something more complex?

Comment: Beckett I also told the same thing to interviewer  but he was expecting some thing more complex.